# Download image from remote website and show to use

Tags: php, curl, proxy

What is the quickest most memory efficient way to download a remote image and then display that to the user? - Note I don't want to save it, I just want to pass it on to the user.

i.e. 
    a user goes to www.website.com/image1.jpg

In the background I would use a getFile script similar to this to retrieve the file, but how do I display this to the user and is this a memory efficient way of doing it?

```
function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='', $fh = '') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    if ($fh != '')
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to download it? `<img src="http://www.website.com/image1.jpg">` will display it to the user from its current origin.

Comment: Im making a proxy like script. Its not a proxy but does a similar(ish) job

Comment: How memory efficient are you talking? Because unless you write your own HTTP client using PHP sockets it's going to need to download the entire image into memory before sending that data back off to the client.

Comment: @Sammitch i was hoping to just somehow pipe it from the return stream to the client, im guessing I dont have that as an option (without, as you say, getting dirty)

Comment: And why not to "write own HTTP client using PHP sockets"? It is pretty easy, especially in case of getting binary image. One (comprehensive) example can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/). One day I have written my own little implementation too :) to scripe external sites' data. I can adapt it to your task and post here, if you need it so far.

Comment: I'd appreciate that thanks @mas.morozov :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
function proxyImage( $fromHost, $path, $bufsize=4096 ) {
  $conn = fsockopen($fromHost,80);
  fwrite( $conn, "GET {$path} HTTP/1.0\r\n" );
  fwrite( $conn, "Host: {$fromHost}\r\n" );
  fwrite( $conn, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0\r\n" );
  fwrite( $conn, "Connection: close\r\n" );
  fwrite( $conn, "\r\n" );

  $answer = ''; 
  while( !feof($conn) and !$bodystarted ) {
    $portion = fread( $conn, $bufsize );
    if( strpos($portion,"\r\n\r\n")!==false ) $bodystarted = true;
    $answer .= $portion;
  }
  list( $headers, $bodypart ) = explode( "\r\n\r\n", $answer, 2 );

  foreach( explode("\r\n",$headers) as $h )
    header($h);

  echo $bodypart;
  while( !feof($conn) )
    echo fread( $conn, $bufsize );
  fclose($conn);
}

proxyImage( 'www.newyorker.com', '/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg' );
```